# What prospects for C++ targeted for web-browser apps?

Tags: c++, c

We have portable C++ source that we use for deploying games and applications on a variety of different hardware (10+ platforms). We're now interested in deploying to web browsers.

Chrome has its Native Client architecture. However, as a platform, we'd be limited to Chrome users.
Are there any any other emerging standards to allow C/C++ source to be compiled and targeted to web browsers?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)?

Comment: @Mat : Wt can self-host, so it can be used for purely-client-side applications as well.

Comment: @ildjarn: well sure. Anything can, if you really want to. I'd say that's "cheating" wrt the question though.

Comment: @Mat : Maybe anything can, but for Wt it's an advertised feature, i.e. a supported and documented use-case.

Comment: Req for clarification: Are all 10+ platforms using the x86 processor? And is this desktop and/or mobile targets? "All the world is not a VAX" is the cry from crusty C programmers like myself. I'd lean strongly towards keeping any C/C++ server-side and optimizing the presentation bandwidth to being manageable by using a good client-server divide.

Comment: Existing code base is compilable for any platform. Would be happy if we could detect, x86, ARM, etc...
Re: Wt. Unless it runs a VM in the webbrowser, I don't think this is a solution. Basically, looking to run some quite heavy number crunching on the client machine. Its possible to do this on the server and stream the GUI to the client, but this is a very expensive route.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% answer for you on this topic any time soon.

The reason is that not one of the main web browsers actually supports running totally secured native compiled code as is C++. ActiveX was never totally secured and it is not 100% known about the suitability of chrome, but then chrome is doing so much in user space. Something like compiled machine code can only really be trusted from a proper sandbox made by the OS kernel.

The upcoming Windows 8 release features new sandboxing technology, that together with the new Windows RT compilers will allow C++ in the browser, and this new code is properly secured.

People who work with Linux are working on different types of sandboxes there as well which are also supported in the kernel. You will probably see these in the distant future as being sandboxes for linux browsers as well as sandboxes for VMS hosting solutions etc...

So for right now, the solution for C++ code is...

1) Google chrome apps
2) windows 8 IE 10 with new Windows 8 Metro Apps etc...

You will have to build your apps for all systems and use the server cookies to identify what build to send to the browser. Much like when there was ActiveX and Mozilla Netscape Plugins before. In other words, the new and upcoming plugin scene will be more secure than ActiveX and Netscape plugins(because it will be properly sandboxed), but it will probably be a lot more expensive and technical because...

1) There will be more vendors of in browser custom machine code plugins.
2) The sandboxes in each OS will be slightly or even very different.
3) The build projects for each OS will be different.
4) You will often most likely have to put the apps in app stores.
5) You will have to have the app verfified by the app store.
6) You might need to pay different app stores if you want to support everywhere.

If the vendors make the sandboxing technology work correctly then a lot of people will use it for obvious reasons, but it will probably be many years if ever before there is some type of standardization of client side sandboxing, which is a really sad thing for everybody. But I think if the browser makers implemented proper sandboxing supported by the OS it would be totally secure, so a lot of web companies would no longer be able to control everything that you do.

Otherwise I am probably over speculating, but thats what I think about C++ and browsers for now. My suggestion, wait some time and do other things. If the sandboxes come, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

[Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) can compile LLVM bitcode (eg generated by Clang from C++) to JavaScript.

Comment: Looks promising. Will check it out. Concerned about performance, but you never know...